# How to create the back of a CD with just CSS?

Tags: css

I'm curious if it's possible to create something like this without the shadows around CSS only.

[image: 1]

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/conic-gradient()

Comment: Quick google of this found https://codepen.io/apollo/pen/MewajX for starters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fun - should get you started.

```css
.cd {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  background: conic-gradient(white, white, white, grey, grey, violet, deepskyblue, aqua, palegreen, yellow, orange, red, grey, grey, white, white, white, white, grey, grey, violet, deepskyblue, aqua, palegreen, yellow, orange, red, grey, grey, white);
}

.cd::before,
.cd::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  border-radius: inherit;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px grey;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.cd::before {
  width: 30%;
  height: 30%;
  margin: -15% 0 0 -15%;
  background: lightgrey;
  background-clip: padding-box; 
  border: 10px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.cd::after {
  width: 18%;
  height: 18%;
  margin: -9% 0 0 -9%;
  background: white;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 10px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 2px grey);
}
```

```html
<div class="cd"></div>
```

Comment: You're welcome. Also, I don't personally care, but no need for profanity - children code these days, as well as people who hold offense to certain language. Cheers!